# How to save Hidden and Added Columns in DataGridView with XML and C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

My app is using a dataGridView with a XML file to save the style and value of the cells in each column. I added two extra columns that are set to `Visible = false`, when I click on "Add Column", it doesn't really ADD a column, it just sets one of the extra columns to `Visible = true`, so I want my app to save that setting(visibility of the columns) so when I re-open the app, the hidden columns I left are still no visible. If I wasn't clear please tell me and I'll try to clarify it.

**EDIT:** I have solved the saving of each column, in a previous question I asked how to save the backColor of the cells in the dataGridView, I got an answer using XML, but, I need that cell BackColor saving to be stored in a TXT file, is there a way to do it?

Comment: you can use some `"settings"` file (a text file is fine), your app reads it every time it starts up, and sets up its components accordingly

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you showed what you have tried

Comment: Yes @chouaib I thought that could be a good idea, but I can't figure out how to make a loop per column

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `loop per column`, I guess you are looking for `foreach(dataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)` ?

Comment: Yes, for loop per column I mean that for each column, a value will be written.

Comment: I will write more detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you save a text file named `"setting.txt"`, let's assume you have 5 columns and their visibility is "`true, true, false, false, true`", so your text file would look like:

**true**

**true**

**false**

**false**

**true**

inside your `Form1_Load` method you can read it and set your columns accordingly like follows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("setting.txt");
   string line;
   int n=0;
   while(!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
     line = sr.ReadLine();

     if(String.Equals(line, "true"))
     {
        dataGridView1.Columns[n++].Visible = true;
     }
     else if(String.Equals(line, "false"))
     {
        dataGridView1.Columns[n++].Visible = false;
     }
   }

   sr.Close();
}
```

Then, at any point, when you change the visibility, save it in your text file's corresponding line as well(programatically), such that the next time you start up your app, it appears in the last settings

Comment: The writing of the visibilty was done correctly, but the last settings did not show.

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss I assume `last settings`=`settings of your dataGridView in the last time you used the app`? am I right? then it didn't show because you didn't update the `"setting.txt"` after each changing of settings, example: If you chang column2.Visibility to `false`, you need to re-write the **third** line in your text file to **false**, that's it

Comment: Last settings is the last change I made on last run of the app. The txt file is written again when I click on a Save Changes button. Before closing the app, I click on that save button and the file is re-written correctly, but I looks like the streamReader isn't doing its work

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss: if it did its work the first time, sure it will do any time. can you open the file with some text editor and see what is written there? then put a break point in `Form1_Load` and try to figure out what is happening with the streamReader

Comment: When I run it for first time is is: `True
True
True
True
True
False
False
True
True
False
False
` I made some changes, then it got like this:`True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
`

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss did you put the break point and tried to debug? btw let's move to chat it's more reliable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70353/discussion-between-chriscreateboss-and-chouaib).

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I did not pay attention to that.